# Oracle query with day name and multiple order by clauses?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So I have three tables: "Theatre", "Show", and "Cast".

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b51h6.png)

### Theatre

1     "Brooklyn"     232
2     "Dallas"       423

### Cast

"Comics"   "The cast that does comic shows"
"Dramatics" "The cast that does drama"

### Show

1   "Brooklyn"    "Comics"   2019-10-10 18:30:00
2   "Dallas"      "Dramatics"   2019-09-09 15:30:00
3    "Brooklyn"   "Dramatics"   2019-08-08 08:00:00
4    "Brooklyn"   "Comics"      2019-07-07  19:00:00
5    "Dallas"      "Dramatics"   2019-09-09 14:30:00

I need to do a list ordered by Theatre name, then date, then time for all shows. Need to list them by theatre name, cast name, name of the day (monday..), and time of show.

Expected output:

```
|  Theatre name  |  Cast name  |     Day     |Time of performance
     "Brooklyn"       "Comics"       "Sunday"      19:00:00
     "Brooklyn"       "Dramatics"    "Thursday"    08:00:00
     "Brooklyn"       "Comics"       "Thursday"    18:30:00
      "Dallas"        "Dramatics"    "Monday"      14:30:00
      "Dallas"        "Comics"       "Monday"      15:30:00
```

So first it needs to order by theatre name, then by date and then by time.

I really stuck on this one. Appreciate any help :)

Comment: dont show image instead mention data format and also expected output data

Comment: Sample data and expected output, please

Answer (score 1):

You need simple order by as following:

```
Select ...
From ...
Order by theatre_name, show_time -- show_time is date data type then it must include date and time both
```

To fetch the day use `to_char(show_time, 'day')` and to fetch the time use `to_char(show_time,'hh24:mi:ss')` .

Please do joins and other stuff in your query by yourself.

Cheers!!